# PHP - Searching for records in a database whilst simultaneously ordering them and paginating them

Tags: php, html, search, pagination

Right, day 8 learning php and I feel that I have tried to do things in the wrong order.... I was fine up until yesterday. I have set myselft the task of creating a fake online book shop (seems popuar with all learn php books). First I created my products and listed them all on a page from the database.. easy, then I used a dropdown box to order the results... hard but did it eventually. Then tried to paginate, easy, then tried to join my ordering code and pagination code: most painful few hours of my life but complete. The I utilised a search bar.. easier then thought, an now I am trying to mix this search bar with my pagination and ordering code and my hair is falling out by the handful! I really wish I had attempted to learn all three at once but would have been a bit of a handful/headful.

So my problem is... It paginates... yay, it orders... yay however when I first see the results from a search... It paginates ok (shows me how many pages there are which is always the correct value) however when I click to view the 2nd page it the stops showing me the results of the search, instead takes me to page 2 of ALL products in the database. The same also happens if I try and order the list, it changes to an ordered list of all the products and tells me the search criteria is empty!

Sorry for such a long winded question, I just cant work out where I have slipped up!

Thank you soo much for anybody who can help!

Heres the code:

booksearch.php:

(have taken out all the irrelevent code!)

```
<?php $query1 = "SELECT *
      FROM booktable";

// execute the query

$results1 = mysql_query($query1)
                or die(mysql_error());

// count the number of rows that are selected from the table

$field = mysql_num_fields( $results1 );

// echo $field;

        for ( $i = 0; $i < $field; $i++ ) 
    {
         $names[$i] = mysql_field_name( $results1, $i );
        }
?>
<form name="searchbook" action="productssearch.php" method="get">
    <br />
    Got For It:<input type="text" id="searchbar" name="searchterm" value="Enter anything and we will search on title, author, publisher and ISBN"></input>
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="Search" value=" - Search - "></input>
  </form>
```

productssearch.php:

```
require "dbconn.php";
$term = $_GET['searchterm'];
$records_per_page = 10;
//If user set the sort order, save to session var - else set default
if(@$_POST['order'])
{    
$_SESSION['order'] = trim($_POST['order']);
}

elseif(!isset($_SESSION['order']))
{    
$_SESSION['order'] = 'bookname';
}

//Determine the total records and pages
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT COUNT(bookname)
          FROM booktable
          WHERE bookname LIKE '%".$term."%'
          OR bookisbn LIKE '%".$term."%'
          OR bookpub LIKE '%".$term."%'
          OR bookauthor LIKE '%".$term."%'");



$total_records = mysql_result($query, 0);
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $records_per_page);

//Set the page to load
$page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 1;
if($page<1 || $page>$total_pages)
{    
$page = 1;
}

//Create limit var for query
$limit_start = ($page-1) * $records_per_page;

//Create and run query for records on current page
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT bookname, bookauthor, bookpub, bookisbn
          FROM booktable
          WHERE bookname LIKE '%".$term."%'
          OR bookisbn LIKE '%".$term."%'
          OR bookpub LIKE '%".$term."%'
          OR bookauthor LIKE '%".$term."%'          
          ORDER BY ".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['order'])." ASC
          LIMIT $limit_start, $records_per_page");


//Prepare output
//**************************************************************
$numrow = mysql_num_rows($query);  
//Create pagination links
$navLinks = '';

//Prev page
if($page > 1)
{    
$prevPage = $page - 1;    
$navLinks .= "<a href='productssearch.php?page=$prevPage'>Prev</a> ";
}
else
{    
$navLinks .= "Prev ";
}

//Individual pages
for($p=1; $p<=$total_pages; $p++)
{
$pageNo = ($p == $page) ? "<b>{$p}</b>" : $p;
$navLinks .= "<a class='pagin' href='productssearch.php?page=$p'>$pageNo</a> ";
}

//next page
if($page < $total_pages)
{    
$nextPage = $page + 1;    
$navLinks .= "<a href='productssearch.php?page=$nextPage'>Next</a>";
}
else
{    
$navLinks .= "Next";
}
?>
```

(IRRELEVANT STUFF FROM MIDDLE REMOVED)

```
<div id="mid"> 
<?php

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";

echo "</td>";
echo "<td class='toprow'>";
echo "Book Title";
echo "</td>";
echo "<td class='toprow'>";
echo "Book Author";
echo "</td>";
echo "<td class='toprow'>";
echo "Book Publisher";
echo "</td>";
echo "<td class='toprow'>";
echo "Book ISBN";
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";

echo "</th>";
echo "</tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
 $bookname = $row['bookname'];
 $bookauthor = $row['bookauthor'];
 $bookpub = $row['bookpub'];
 $bookisbn = $row['bookisbn'];
  // send the values to the browser as a row in a html table
  echo "<tr>";

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>";
  echo "<a href='addtolist.php?bookname=".$bookname."&bookauthor=".$bookauthor."&bookpub=".$bookpub."&bookisbn=".$bookisbn."'>Add to basket</a>";

  echo "</td>";

 echo "<td>";
  echo $bookname;
  echo "</td>";

  echo "<td>";
  echo $bookauthor;
  echo "</td>";

  echo "<td>";
  echo $bookpub;
  echo "</td>";

  echo "<td>";
  echo $bookisbn;
  echo "</td>";

  echo "</tr>";


}
?>
</table>


<?php 
echo "<br />";
echo $navLinks; ?>
```

Please note I am a real beginner so I am not learning how to make secure or safe code.,.. I havnt even encrypted user and admin passwords yet... just trying to learn the mechanics of the script!

Thank you all again for taking the time to read my "windy" question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To all who are reading this: I'm keeping it SIMPLE, as Phil has commented he's a beginner.  We all know there are considerations that are NOT being taken into account in this answer!

Phil, the answer lies in the construction of your navlinks code.

When you click one of the navlinks, it passes the limits for your pagination, but does NOT pass the search term.

You would need to modify your navlinks to be along the lines of:

```
$navLinks .= "<a href='productssearch.php?page=$prevPage&searchterm=$term'>Prev</a> ";
```

and

```
$navLinks .= "<a class='pagin' href='productssearch.php?page=$psearchterm=$term'>$pageNo</a> ";
```

and

```
$navLinks .= "<a href='productssearch.php?page=$nextPage&searchterm=$term'>Next</a>";
```

etc.

Comment: I did read the comment above and just... worked it out but you confirmed it! Thank you for you brilliant and quick responce! And thank you for being kind to a beginner... A lot of people in the q&A forums are not quite so understanding. [=

Comment: Sorry, the order bit still is not working, everything else is, however when I choose a field to re-order by, it goes back to removing the searchterm so displays all products! Have you any ideas? thanks

Comment: Same idea, you have to add the terms/pagination to the sort links.

Comment: to sort the order I use an if else statement to say if order is set to this then insert this into the SQL query. this means the only page link is in the html form (in action=""). I tried putting the following....... <form name="sort" action="productssearch.php<?php echo "&searchterm=$term";?>" method="post">

but unfortunately this doesnt work

Comment: needed to replace the '&' for a '?'
Thank you for all your help

Comment: not sure the fair way to scor but as you helped me answer both parts I gave you the tick lol

Answer (score 2):

It's becuase you are not carrying your:

```
$term = $_GET['searchterm'];
```

to the next page.

So when you search a blank string you are getting returned back the results for everything.

Your pagination links should contain the search term used in your POST.

Comment: so would something like $navLinks .= "<a href='productssearch.php?page=$prevPage&searchterm=".$term."'>Prev</a> ";
.
suffice?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, the order bit still is not working, everything else is however when I choose a field to reorder by it goes back to removing the searchterm so displays all products! Have you any ideas? thanks